# Angular POST request - error reading response

Tags: node.js, api, firebase, http, google-cloud-functions

I have a rather simple situation. I make a call to an endpoint in my Google Cloud Functions, it sends a simple response. I try to console.log.

*Angular component*

```
async submitHandler(formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
    this.loading = true;

    const formValue = JSON.stringify(this.reqForm.value);

    this.http.post('https://myApp.cloudfunctions.net/myEndpoint', formValue)
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.success = true;
            formDirective.resetForm();
        }, 
        (err) => { console.log(err) });

    this.loading = false;
}
```

*Google Cloud Function*

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.myEndpoint = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    return cors(req, res, () => {


        const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
        const name = body.name;
        console.log("REQUEST BODY >>> ", body);
        console.log("REQUEST NAME >>> ", name);


        if (!name) {
            res.status(400).send('missing name!')
        }


        res.send(name.split('').reverse().join(''))

    });

});
```

The cloud function responds with the `name` field reversed. So, `"name": "Kenny"` would respond with `"ynneK"`. That's what I should see in my front end when I `console.log(res)`.

Here's my front end **error**:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://myApp.cloudfunctions.net/myEndpoint", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttp…, text: "llaH ynneK"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://myApp.cloudfunctions.net/myEndpoint"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://myApp.cloudfunctions.net/myEndpoint"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

As you can see in the second line of *"error: {.."* I have `text: "llaH ynneK"}`. So, I don't think it's a server problem, I think it's a local Angular problem.

What am I doing wrong? Should I set response headers to application/json in the cloud function endpoint? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The flow is:

1. `JSON.stringify` form data and send in post request (seemed to be the only way it'd work)
2. GCF endpoint gets it and `JSON.parse(req.body)`
3. endpoint does it's thing, then sends back to client `res.send()`
4. Client gets response to make sure all is well, but the error occurs when trying to read it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `res.send(name.split('').reverse().join(''))` is sending back unquoted text string which is not valid JSON.

Comment: Wow, you're exactly right! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it and we can close the book on this. :b